# What is the best way to use Panels

Tags: panels

I have D6 and the Panels module installed.

I want to be able to control the entire page layout from within Drupal itself, without having to write any new code such as a template file etc

To achieve this, I create a very basic template file which includes the standard html, style, body elements etc and just:

```
<?php print $content; ?>
```

This works great, it allows me to for example create a Panel layout for different page layouts, but it also allows me to create full-page landing pages without header/footer etc

The only drawback is that for pages that dont have a Panels template, say for example the user login page, how do I then style/structure this page?

Comment: would you be able to post the 'basic' template page in its entireity? I'm attempting to do the same thing of setting up the whole layouts and am trying to not re-invent the wheel (new drupal user here...)

Comment: hey @g19fanatic, it literally contains:

<head>
  <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <?php print $styles; ?>
  <?php print $scripts; ?>
</head>
<body class="<?php print $classes; ?>">

  <?php print $content; ?>

  <?php print $page_closure; ?>

  <?php print $closure; ?>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Panels handles all of the layout within $content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this article:

http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2011/09/13/drupal-customized-user-registrationloginforgot-password-page-with-panel/

Which describes how to workaround this issue with Panels.

This worked well for me, didnt take long at all, but it seems a little hackish. If anybody knows a better way please let me know.